# How can we dissipate the heat from a block of 10*10*3 mm with 100 degree Celsius without losing the portability of the block?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer, heat-exchanger, cryogenics

I have a Peltier's device of 10*10*3mm and the material is Bismuth Telluride. The hot side is 100 $^oC$ and I want to dissipate the heat, and at the same time, the device should be portable i.e. it should not be part of the system so that I can't take it with me.

I tried using a vapor chamber and heat pipes. Though I want something lightweight, reliable and effective.

Comment: Is it radioactive? How is the temperature clamped at 100°C? What is the material? Why do you need to carry it around?

Comment: It is a Peltier's device. the material is Bismuth-telluride. I want to make use of it in a portable device.

Comment: there are small packets a bit  larger than standard sugar packets containing two components  that once squeezed and kneaded will generate heat, for ski boots in very cold days. you may search for it.

Comment: Do you know what is it specifically called? @kamran

Comment: You might want to look into "electrostatic cooling". I read about this a long time ago, don't know if it ever became practical. The idea is you shoot high voltage static electricity at a hot object and the static electricity breaks down the boundary layers of air allowing the object to cool off quickly.

Comment: @AdarshShubhananda, here is a link to one model, but I had seen a reusable version too. I got battery operated boots and gloves some years back, so I don't use them anymore. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01NCR69ZG?ie=UTF8&tag=bustle7912-20&camp=1789&linkCode=xm2&creativeASIN=B01NCR69ZG

Comment: What do you mean by saying the hot side is 100 $^o$C? Is this saying, the Peltier element is attached permanently to something at that temperature? What do you mean, the cooling side should "not be part of the system"? Anything that is attached to cool the system is by definition part of the system.

Comment: @jeffrey Its obvious that it has a cold side too, as it is a peltier device. I m worried about the dissipation of heat from the hot side. There are certain solutions but it will lead the peltier device to get attached with a system that wont be portable. I m looking forward to make this device portable with some efficient cooling technology. Something which is small in size n shape and can dissipate heat.THANKS

Comment: What is obvious to you is not obvious in the question. I would like to see a drawing of the entire system. I would like to know where the device is attached (hot and/or cold sides). I would like an example of a proposal that does not work.